# Wavelet based interpolation

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, interpolation, wavelet

How do I do Wavelet based interpolation (simple zero-padding scheme) in matlab?

I did wavedec2 on an image, and zeroize the vertical, horizontal and diagonal domains, interpolated the 4 domains to a larger size, but it did not outperform spatial based interpolators (bilinear, nearest, bicubic) as stated in several papers.

Please advise.

Thank you.

Comment: reference to the "several papers"?

Comment: I seriously think it was unreasonable and unjust to close my question previously without hearing enough of it as a gradually developing discussion. And they deduct points unjustly. :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question but the [Matlab Pyramid Toolbox](http://www.cns.nyu.edu/~lcv/software.php) and [Peter Kovesi's computer vision/image process functions](http://www.csse.uwa.edu.au/~pk/research/matlabfns/) has a lot of wavelet functions that should probably do what you want.